# How to set title of a website dynamically before opening it on the basis of search query

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, search, seo

Suppose i am searching on google, best tution classes in xyz and result comes with various sites listed on search engine having title, Top tution classes in xyz. After opening the page, data is also shown for xyz location. But, the page with kind of title doesn't exist. The page which exists is only one that shows data based on different parameters after opening it. How to achieve this? Please help...

I searched on google, youtube, but didn't find anything. Is it a case of template engine or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a page on the fly from the search results  Search engines never index pages until they actually exist.

You have to start by creating pages for each location and filling them in with enough content that Google thinks they are worthy of getting indexed.

Then when somebody does that search in Google and your site shows up in the results, they can click to the URL on your site for a specific location.